# C# Dictionary: Multiple KEYS per Value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to get multiple **keys** with a single *value*. Yes, I've already used the search function, but most answers are for the opposite direction (multiple **values** per *key*), but I want the opposite.

The reasoning behind this is that I want keep multiple Item-IDs (it's for a Bot) per "main" ID, and throwing those multiple IDs into a value of the one is too slow to modify (looking for one value => looping trough all main IDs & getting each value, then checking if that ID exists).

**Example**

```
Key 1 => Value
Key 2 => Value
Key 3 => Value
Key 4 => Value
Key 5 => Value 2
```

Looking for Value should return: Key 1-4, not 5

So I'm looking for a way to do that easier - like I said above.

Anyone knows if that's possible and how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make a composite key (it can be an object, you know) but search by such key would be less than optimal

Comment: Could you show some example input/output, perhaps what operations you want to call on this data structure.

Comment: What are you trying to enforce here, exactly? Given your example what you call `Value` is actually the key, and your actual value need only be a collection.

Comment: It sounds like you're just calling a key a value and a value a key, which is what's confusing you, and you really want to just have multiple values per key.  You say, "Looking for Value".  You don't search on values, you search on keys.  If you're searching on "Value" then that should be the key, not the value.

Comment: Added an example above, hopefully that shows it.

Comment: @user1818486 Your example makes it pretty plain that your problem is exactly what you say it's not, namely multiple values per key.

Comment: Isn't searching trough all values for one key somehow slow?

Comment: @user1818486 Yes, which is why you don't search for values, you search for keys.  Your example has you searching on values, which you shouldn't do.  If you meant that searching for any of the keys, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 should all return `Value`, then you have your keys right.  If you want to search for `Value` and get `1, 2, 3, 4, and 5` then you're backwards.

Comment: What I am trying to do is a trading Bot (for virtual Items).
You put up 5 refined (metal) and get one key, if you remove one metal, the key should be removed too. So I have to save all the metal id's to the key, which gives me this weird situation

Comment: "throwing those multiple IDs into a value of the one is too slow to modify" Can you explain what is slow. Please include the code you have written so far, there may be better solutions but we need to see what you are doing before we can make a recommendation.

Comment: It's just an expectation, considering the operations behind a Dictionary and then additionally a List for example. So before I write code which might be extremly slow, I want to look for alternatives

Comment: Suggestions: DON'T use a dictionary. Take a look at [NameValueCollection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) instead.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the dictionary the other way around and make the value a list of items.

if for example `Value` is a string and `Key 1-4` are ints your dictionary could look something like:

```
var theDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

retrieving `Value` by `theDictionary["Value"]` would then return a list of ints containing 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Edit - Added example:

```
var theDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        {"Value", new List<string> {"Key 1", "Key 2", "Key 3", "Key 4", "Key 5",}},
        {"Value2", new List<string> {"Key 5", "Key 2"}}
    };

var oneToFour = theDictionary["Value"];
```

Comment: I think that's still the easiest variant for me then. Thanks all!

Comment: How about the other way around... give a `key` get the `value`

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**
Looking at your edit, it really looks like you have designed this `Dictionary` backwards... your keys should be for matching values, not your values for matching keys.

You could do something like create a dictionary that maps outer-keys to inner-keys, then use the inner-key to index a second dictionary.

Example:

```
var outer = new Dictionary<int, Guid> {
  { 1, GuidA },
  { 2, GuidA },
  { 3, GuidA },
  { 4, GuidA },
  { 5, GuidB }
};
var inner = new Dictionary<Guid, Value> {
  { GuidA, Value1 },
  { GuidB, Value2 }
};
```

You would access it as: `value = outer[inner[key]]`.

Answer (score 5):

You may be overthinking your problem.  Keys need to be unique in order to be useful for lookup operations.  Values do not need to be unique.  Multiple keys can point to the same value without causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

1) Servy is absolutely correct.  If you're doing a search on anything but a key ... and if you're trying to retrieve anything but the corresponding value ... then something is definitely wrong.  All things being equal, you probably DON'T want a dictionary.

2) Based on what you're saying, perhaps a better collection type might be a List. Specifically, a list of name/value pairs.

EXAMPLE:

```
List<string> NVList = new List<string>();
NVList.Add("color=blue");
...
```

3) Note that .Net has a specialized "NameValueCollection" class that might be *IDEAL* for you:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your initial dictionary (mapping your keys to values) already you can use some Linq to convert it into a reverse dictionary without having to create that reverse dictionary by hand.

```
var newDict = initialDict.Select(x=>x.Value).Distinct().ToDictionary(x=>x, x=> initialDict.Where(kvp=>kvp.Value == x).Select(kvp=>kvp.Key));
```

Select the distinct `originalValues` from your original dictionary and use those as your `newKeys`.  Your `newValues` are the set of your `originalKeys` that mapped to each `originalValue`/`newKey`.

---

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dhwUSC

Given an initial dictionary of

```
var initialDict = new Dictionary<int, string>{
        {1, "Value"},
        {2, "Value"},
        {3, "Value"},
        {4, "Value"},
        {5, "Value2"}
    };
```

the above function returns

```
Value: {1, 2, 3, 4}
Value2: {5}
```